# Is there any way to make ClientHttp stack to use browser cookies?

Tags: c#, silverlight, cookies, httpwebrequest, clienthttpstack

Suppose user already has logged into the remote system, so he has a session associated with his username and access to his private data. Now there is a Silverlight application, which tries to communicate with server through `HttpWebRequest` (ClientHttp stack). Is there any way to pass the user session to the Silverlight app? Somehow share the cookie with the browser maybe?

**Update:**

There are code snippets around the web and on SO as well that show how to transfer HttpOnly cookies from `WebBrowser` control to `WebRequest` via  `InternetGetCookieEx` (e.g. [Use a WebBrowser to login into a site that use HttpOnly cookie](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/12/use-a-webbrowser-to-login-into-a-site-that-use-httponly-cookie/)). Two things that I didn't understand yet are - if this can be used in browser silverlight app and if cookies can be similarly transfered from the browser in which silverlight app is running to the silverlight app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the forms authentication cookie or the ASP.NET session cookie because those cookies are session only cookies (emitted with the HttpOnly flag) meaning that they are not accessible to client scripting. If you want to achieve that you could have the server explicitly pass the value of the cookie to the SL application as parameter in the generated markup.

Comment: There are code snippets around the web and on SO as well that show how to transfer HttpOnly cookies from WebBrowser control to WebRequest via  InternetGetCookieEx (e.g. http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/04/12/use-a-webbrowser-to-login-into-a-site-that-use-httponly-cookie/). Two things that I didn't understand yet are - if this can be used in browser silverlight app and if cookies can be similarly transfered from the browser in which silverlight app is running to the silverlight app itself?

Comment: No, this cannot be used in a Silverlight application. The `InternetGetCookieEx` is a Win32 function which in order to be invoked you need to be authorized to do P/Invoke calls, which in Silverlight is absolutely impossible, unless of course you have installed this Silverlight application as an out of browser application on the client desktop. This can be used in a rich client application such as WPF for example.